# Recommended code for the Youtube video src

Tags: javascript, html5-video

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5Asua4YsrEE?autoplay=1&modestbranding=0&controls=0"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to ask about my code,

I want to make a video player with a source from youtube using iframe where control, title, brand disabled, and autoplay are enabled.

but after I tried it didn't seem like it worked.

Can anyone provide some help to correct my code or suggest code in some other form using js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide hide the title and the brand by setting a height for the parent of the iframe and using `overflow: hidden`

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/dyXvbap)

Comment: great, I didn't think of an idea like that.

after I implemented it would be better if I set the height = width or make the size of the height longer,

example: 1280 x 720 is changed to 1280 x 1000

after that set the margins on the css to be like this

 iframe {
      margin-top: -5%;
      margin-bottom: -5%;
    }

that way the original video size will not be trimmed,
thanks again for the great idea

Comment: after I did some experiments yesterday it seemed like setting up a command like this was not possible

autoplay = 1 & modestbranding = 0 & controls = 0

I can only use one of them

or the '&' symbol doesn't work?

Comment: No worries! Chrome will only autoplay videos that are muted, so add &mute=1 to the url and it will work. I updated the codepen. https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/dyXvbap :)